# How to retained the state of datetime Dialog on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

On the orientation change, the Activity is recreated and Date Time Dialog also recreated.
I want to save the State of the Date Time Dialog that has been changed by the User.

Before I  Dismiss the Dialog I want to retained the state of the Date Time Dialog.

Note, I can dismiss the dialog in onSaveInstanceState, where I have the bundle available. But, it is also called when the activity goes in paused state, and in that case I don't want to dismiss the dialog. Hence, decided to dismiss it on onDestroy method, but I don't have the bundle object there. Which is why I am facing this problem. Is there any way to access the bundle in the onDestroy? Or any other suggestion for my problem would be appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(dateTimeDialog !=null && dateTimeDialog.isShowing())
    {
        //<HERE I WANT THE STATE TO BE SAVED IN THE BUNDLE>
        dateTimeDialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Basically we lock the application if user move away from our application, and on unlock the screen and the dialog he is viewing are resumed. And if we dismissed the dialog on onSavedInstanceState, after unlocking the application it invokes onRestart, start and resume methods, where none of these have the instance of Bundle supplied as parameter.

Also, we have separate layouts for landscape & portrait because of which we cannot set the configChanges="orientation" in the manifest file.

Comment: `DatePickerDialog` class has `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still retain your Dialog states in `onSaveIsntanceState()`, but only dismiss the dialog in `onDestroy()`, which should satisfy your requirement. Though I am not sure what would a dialog dismissal in `onDestroy()` accomplish.

Comment: yes,That's true! and works fine but I wanted to retained the dialog after unlock my Device and when I dismiss the dialog in onSaveInstanceState() it is also called when the activity goes in paused state, and in that case I don't want to dismiss the dialog. Hence, decided to dismiss it on onDestroy method, but I don't have the bundle object there.

Answer (score 0):

use the below line in manifest file in actvity tags

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

like

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and override below the method in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

No need to use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState()

Please let me know status after adding ablove code

Comment: I have updated the question and mentioning the reason why I'm not using the configChanges.